# print odd and even numbers using two threads in java efficiently?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, runnable

I was asked below question in an interview where I need to print out even and odd numbers using two threads so I came up with below code but in this I am using two classes one which implements runnable interface and other to print out the number which uses `wait` and `notifyAll`.

```
public class PrintEvenOddTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Output print = new Output();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new EvenOddTask(print, 10, false));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new EvenOddTask(print, 10, true));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}


class EvenOddTask implements Runnable {
  private int max;
  private Output print;
  private boolean isEvenNumber;

  EvenOddTask(Output print, int max, boolean isEvenNumber) {
    this.print = print;
    this.max = max;
    this.isEvenNumber = isEvenNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    int number = isEvenNumber == true ? 2 : 1;
    while (number <= max) {
      if (isEvenNumber) {
        print.printEven(number);
      } else {
        print.printOdd(number);
      }
      number += 2;
    }
  }
}


class Output {
  boolean isOdd = false;

  public synchronized void printEven(int number) {
    while (isOdd == false) {
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Even:" + number);
    isOdd = false;
    notifyAll();
  }

  public synchronized void printOdd(int number) {
    while (isOdd == true) {
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Odd:" + number);
    isOdd = true;
    notifyAll();
  }
}
```

I wanted to check whether there is any better or simple way to do these kind of tasks in Java 7. In general instead of using another `Output` class, can I not print out directly in `EvenOddTask` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so in the following ways :

1. **Without using synchronization :**

   ```
   class Print {

       private static int count = 1;
       private static int MAX = 20;
       private boolean isOdd = true;

       public void printEven() {
           while (true) {
               if (count > MAX) break;
               if (!isOdd) {
                   System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + count++);
                   isOdd = true;
               }
           }
       }

       public void printOdd() {
           while (true) {
               if (count > MAX) break;
               if (isOdd) {
                   System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + count++);
                   isOdd = false;
               }
           }
       }

   }

   public class ThreadOddEven {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Print p = new Print();

           // Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> p.printEven());
           Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {     
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 p.printEven();                
              }
           });
           t1.setName("EVEN");

           // Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> p.printOdd());
           Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 p.printOdd(); 
              }
           });
           t2.setName("ODD");

           t1.start();
           t2.start();
       }

   }
   ```

   This is probably the most easiest way to achieve printing odd and
   even numbers across two threads.

   Here we are just using a boolean variable `isOdd`. This value gets
   toggled after each thread prints a value.
2. **Using synchronization :**

   ```
   class Print2 {

       private static int count = 1;
       private static int MAX = 10;
       private Object obj = new Object();

       public void printEven() {
           while (true) {
               if (count > MAX) break;
               synchronized (obj) {
                   System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count++);
                   obj.notify();
                   try {
                       obj.wait();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
               }
           }
       }

       public void printOdd() {
           while (true) {
               if (count > MAX) break;
               synchronized (obj) {
                   System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + count++);
                   obj.notify();
                   try {
                       obj.wait();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```

   In the second example instead of using a boolean variable, we are
   using an object so that we can synchronize the calls between both
   threads.

   The main method call to this class is the same as the above example.

Comment: This is much simpler looks like. Thanks a lot. Only confusion I have is we don't have any synchronization and locks here so how this is working? I mean how it prints out odd first and even next without any synchronization between threads? Also if possible can you edit this example in Java 7 so that I can understand better?

Comment: lambdas seem to be added only in Java 8

Comment: Also we dont implement `Runnable` interface here?

Comment: we don't need to make `count` and `isOdd` volatile here?

Comment: Yeah this is a terrible solution.  There's no synchronization anywhere.

Comment: yeah thats what I was also confuse bcoz I don't see any synchronization. I thought we may need to synchronize things between two threads and use `volatile` for `count` and `isOdd` variable atleast.

Comment: @markspace : I don't think its a terrible solution. Run it and see for yourself, why do you need to use synchronization just to print odd and even numbers for *2 threads* ?

Comment: Because it's required by the language specification.  "I tried it once and it works" is a terrible way to test.  You're sharing data (fields) between two threads; you must synchronize.

Comment: @flash : You wouldn't need to use it because unless and until the flag is toggled the other thread will not be able to print values.

Comment: @markspace : For this scenario I don't think so. If you can show me a scenario where this fails I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: In the current question, under what scenario it can fail or not work correctly? I am also thinking from interview perspective if someone asks me that we are sharing data between two threads and he starts asking me to synchronize then what things we need to take care of in this program?

Comment: @flash : If you can prove to the interviewer that you wouldn't need `synchronization` in this case (like I'm doing) I'm sure anyone would be amazed. The views of an interviewer are *subjective*. One may appreciate it and the other may not.

Comment: Got it but for my understanding perspective can you help me understand if we needed to synchronize this then how we would have done it? It is just for my knowledge and understanding. Or can you create an example here where we needed synchronization then that will help me as well.

Comment: @flash : Please check the edit. *You can explain both methods for your next interview and blow the interviewers mind*.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Also if I use second solution with synchronization then it prints opposite. For example: `EVEN : 1
ODD : 2
EVEN : 3
ODD : 4
EVEN : 5`

Comment: You'll need to rename the threads in that case (I've omitted it for brevity). Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181777/discussion-between-flash-and-nicholas-k).